# VSTO Addin Dialog Box

Tags: c#

I have a dialog box popup in a VSTO addin for outlook 2013.  I test for DialogResult.Yes and No, to which I have set the two buttons' results.  They work fine, but I want yet another behavior when the user cancels out of the box.  When they press cancel the code just continues.  Is there something I can call to stop the addin from executing if they cancel the dialog box?   How can I test for the cancel button?  I tried `res == DialogResult.Cancel`  but it can't cast res to bool and it's type DialogResult because I also test for Yes and No.

How can I tell if they press the cancel button, and how can I exit the addin.  In python the command would be `sys.exit()` What is the C# equivalent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox class for displaying dialog boxes in the add-in you may use the following code for checking the chosen option:

```
// Display message box
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);

// Process message box results 
switch (result)
{
    case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
        // User pressed Yes button 
        // ... 
        break;
    case MessageBoxResult.No:
        // User pressed No button 
        // ... 
        break;
    case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
        // User pressed Cancel button 
        // ... 
        break;
 }
```

See [Dialog Boxes Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in MSDN for more information.

If you developed your own window you may add an event handler for the button's Click event.

Comment: what namespace is MessageBoxResult in?  I tried  doing result = DialogResult.Cancel and got "Could not cast DialogResult to boolean"  Also it is a form with ShowDialog() not a MessageBox()  Oh and I don't have a cancel button I want to use the X at the top right of the dialog box

Comment: - Use [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) if your application is a WinForms application
 - Use [MessageBoxResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxresult.aspx) if your application is a WPF/Silverlight application
 Namespaces are different: `System.Windows.Forms` (Winforms) vs `System.Windows` (WPF).

Comment: Oh I see, I added a cancel button, but is there a way to capture the X click event

Comment: The Form class provides the [Closing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: Ok cool, now if I capture that event how can I mimic the sys.exit() Python behavior that stops all execution.  Otherwise my addin would continue and I want it to stop if they cancel this dialog.

Comment: I captured the closing event, but that just stops that logic from executing, I want to completely stop the addin, so no more code is executed.  How can I end an addin similar to Python's sys.exit() as I mentioned.

Comment: You can't unload the add-in where the code runs. But you can disable all UI controls and event handlers. For example, you can set a global boolean variable which can be checked at any time. Also you can use the **Connect** property of the COMAddIn class to unload add-ins programmatically.

Comment: Can you give me a small example of closing an addin  in this fashion?

Comment: See [Programmatically unloading an Addin](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9eb74bc6-7d29-4a1c-a860-35933486d500/programmatically-unloading-an-addin?forum=vsto)